# Virtualization Enabled in BIOS but not enabled in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, virtualization, hardware-virtualization

I am trying to install WSL which of course requires virtualization to be on. I tried enabling it in bios, but windows 10 refuses to enable it. I have tried completely disabling Hyper-V, and disabling virtualization, booting, then shutting down, then reenabling virtualization. Nothing has worked. I don't have any 3rd party antivirus, and I don't have fast boot enabled. I am very confused why it just is not enabling. Any ideas? Would a reinstall of windows help?

cpu: i7 10700kf

mobo: asrock z490m-itx/ac

[virtualization says disabled in task manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNhXm.png)

[virtualization on in bios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNvI4.jpg)

Comment: If my answer doesnt work, could you provide the exact error message your are getting when doing exactly what with wsl ?

Answer (score 1):

In your BIOS/UEFI, under Chipset Configuration, you will also find an option called VT-d ([User Manual 4.6.2 Chipset Configuration (page 65)](https://download.asrock.com/Manual/Z490M-ITXac.pdf). You should have this enabled too.

Comment: It might be a good idea to also enavble SGX (on the Advanced\CPU Configuration page).

Comment: Yep, vt-d is enabled too

Comment: I just enabled SGX and it looks like virtualization is enabled now. Not sure why that would work, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the
[Intel Processor Identification Utility](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005495/processors.html)
to verify if your system is capable of Intel Virtualization Technology.

The result should look like this:

[image]